# How do I add a URL link in QnA-maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker, web-chat

Does anyone know how to add URL links to the answer in QnA maker?

As it is right now I can only see that you are able to add straight text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QnA maker will always respond with a text answer, rendering links will mostly be **dependent on what formats are supported for the channel** in question. For example, the standard webchat control by default and used in the emulator support basic markdown formatting. So, if I wanted to render links in those, I would store my 'answer url' in markdown format and train the QnA service that way, i.e

```
[name of your link](https://url.com)
```

This answer box on stack overflow supports markdown, which i'm using to render [this link](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/08/25/qna-maker-rich-card-attachments-net/).

However, different channels (facebook, slack, etc) may support different formats. If you are using your own custom webchat, you can define supported formats on your own [following this guide](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/)

Knowing that the QnA service will always return a string as an answer, you should be easily able to parse/consume the string as you wish in the bot code, and have it render as a link based on what channel you're on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what about opening to a new. browser (tab or window).  in other words, how do I code, target="_blank"?

Comment: also ... i have found that if the markdown link is inside an ac-container (class for a CARD widget), then it adds a class="ac-anchor" and target="_blank" which totally defeats my link.